# Javascript Bookmark Button not update items instantly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blogger

I tried to create a bookmark system for my website where anyone can add posts in bookmark list and remove them too. But the problem I am having is that, when anyone add an item by clicking `<span id="like-01" class="like-btn">Bookmark</span>` span, it stores item in `bookmark-items` div and shows or count added items numbers in `<div class="bookmarked-num">0</div>`. But when I remove the item from bookmark lists, it actually removes from the `bookmark-items` and decrease the number from `bookmarked-num` div too. But this time its not live. I mean I can see it if I reload the page. How can I make it live ? I mean `bookmark-items` and `bookmarked-num` will update instantly when remove an item by toggling.

Here's my approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a.panel-group_btn {color: #888;display:block;}
        a.like-btn { color: #888; font-size: 14px; }
        span.clicked { color: #00dfae; font-weight:bold; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bookmarked-num">0</div>
<div class="panel-group_btn">
    <a href="www.google.com" class="entry-title">This is a post</a>
    <div class='job-post-page-featured-bg ' expr:data-image='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/19/23/46/church-1993645_640.jpg'></div>
    <span id="like-01" class="like-btn">Bookmark</span>
</div>
<div class="bookmark-items"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function updateBookmarkedNum() {
        var bookmarkCount = $(".bookmark-items .bookmarked-item").length;
        $(".bookmarked-num").text(bookmarkCount);
    }
    $(".like-btn").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        var btnStorage = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
            var title = $(this).siblings(".entry-title").text();
            var image = $(this).siblings(".job-post-page-featured-bg").attr("expr:data-image");
            var url = $(this).siblings(".entry-title").attr("href");
            var bookmarkItem = `
                <div class="bookmarked-item" id="${btnStorage}">
                    <a href="${url}" class="bookmark-title">${title}</a>
                    <img src="${image}" alt="Bookmark Image">
                    <button class="remove-btn">Remove from bookmark</button>
                </div>`;
            $(".bookmark-items").append(bookmarkItem);
            localStorage.setItem(btnStorage, 'true');
            updateBookmarkedNum();
        } else {
            $("#" + btnStorage).removeClass('clicked');
            $("#" + btnStorage).siblings(".remove-btn").parent().remove();
            localStorage.removeItem(btnStorage);
            updateBookmarkedNum();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".remove-btn", function () {
        var itemId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        $("#" + itemId).removeClass('clicked');
        $("#" + itemId).siblings(".remove-btn").parent().remove();
        localStorage.removeItem(itemId);
        $(this).parent().remove(); 
        updateBookmarkedNum();
    });
    $(".like-btn").each(function () {
        var mainlocalStorage = $(this).attr("id");
        if (localStorage.getItem(mainlocalStorage) === 'true') {
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
            var title = $(this).siblings(".entry-title").text();
            var image = $(this).siblings(".job-post-page-featured-bg").attr("expr:data-image");
            var url = $(this).siblings(".entry-title").attr("href");
            var bookmarkItem = `
                <div class="bookmarked-item" id="${mainlocalStorage}">
                    <a href="${url}" class="bookmark-title">${title}</a>
                    <img src="${image}" alt="Bookmark Image">
                    <button class="remove-btn">Remove from bookmark</button>
                </div>`;
            $(".bookmark-items").append(bookmarkItem);
        }
    });
    updateBookmarkedNum();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Bookmark not shows live / instant data when remove items by toggling items.